# getViewLifeCycleOwner() vs 'this' vs this.getActivity() in Androidx Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

We utilize LiveData's `observe` method quite a bit in our fragments. A recent release of the androidx fragment sdk is leading to Android Studio marking instances of `liveDataObject.observe(this)` as incorrect in favor of `liveDataObject.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner())` .

> Added a new Lint check that ensures you are using getViewLifecycleOwner() when observing LiveData from onCreateView(), onViewCreated(), or onActivityCreated(). (b/137122478)
>   https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment

We are worried about implementing this change because we do not understand how the functionality of `getViewLifecycleOwner()` compares to that of using `this`, and whether it will cause a conflict with the use of `this` or `this.getActivity()` when setting up the ViewModel in the fragment.

Additionally, we use the Android Navigation component and noticed that when the user navigates to different fragments within the same activity, each fragment's `onDestroyView()` method is called, **but not `onDestroy()`**

Here is an example of our code in `onViewCreated()`

```
 vm.getStemLengths().observe(this, stemLengths -> {
        this.stemLengths = new ArrayList<>(Stream.of(stemLengths).map(stemLength ->
                new SearchModel(Integer.toString(stemLength.getValue()))).toList());
  });
```

Later, in `onDestroyView()`

```
 vm.getStemLengths().removeObservers(this);
```

At the same time, depending on the fragment, the ViewModel that houses the LiveData is set up with one of the following:

```
 vm = new ViewModelProvider(this.getActivity()).get(PrepareVM.class);
```

To persist the viewmodel across fragments in the activity.

Or:

```
vm = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(AprobacionVM.class);
```

If the VM does not need to be persisted outside of the current fragment

So to summarize, will changing `this` to `getViewLifeCycleOwner()` when observing LiveData objects in fragments' `onCreateView()` conflict with the ViewModel patterns / Navigation component? Could there be an instance for example where the livedata change ends up triggering an observer from a previous fragment in the same activity that a user navigates away from?

From the documentation of getViewLifeCycleOwner it seems that making this change may allow us to remove the `removeObservers()` call in each fragment's `onDestroyView()`. Is that the correct understanding?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Fragment` implements `LifecycleOwner` which maps its create and destroy events to the fragment's `onCreate` and `onDestroy`, respectively.

`Fragment.getViewLifecycleOwner()` maps its create and destroy events to the fragment's `onViewCreated` and `onDestroyView`, respectively. The precise sequence is described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#getViewLifecycleOwner()).

If you're working with views in your observers, you'll want the view lifecycle. Otherwise you might get updates when the view hierarchy is invalid, which may lead to crashes.

> From the documentation of getViewLifeCycleOwner it seems that making this change may allow us to remove the removeObservers() call in each fragment's onDestroyView().

Correct.

Comment: Thanks for the response! on one hand the removeObservers() call in onDestroyView() is no longer needed, but on the other hand getViewLifecycleOwner() uses the fragment's onDestroy() method. So if the onDestroy() method does not get called (as is our case only onDestroyView() gets called when the user navigates away), the live data observer will not be removed, correct?

Comment: `onDestroyView`, a pretty bad typo on my part, sorry. View lifecycle does end with `onDestroyView`.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a bug with it. If you do a new Intent for a fragment already use it gives getView is null error. Why? The activity is newly creared.